# Javascript autocomplete in Qualtrics fails to show below the question

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, qualtrics

I've implemented the following javascript code to use the autocomplete feature within the text field question in Qualtrics.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    var textOptions = [

        "Adam", "Athelney", "Baring"

];
    jQuery('.QR-' + this.questionId).autocomplete({
        source: textOptions,
        minLength: 3
    });

});
```

The code works; however, the autocomplete suggestions appears at the end of the page (below "Powered by Qualtrics" URL link). See the first screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure whether this is a bug within Qualtrics; however, I've tested the same code on an account provided by a different University (see the second screenshot below) where the same code works as expected (the suggestion appears right below the question, not at the end of the page) so I am left puzzled by this behavior.

[image: Qualtrics screenshot 2]

Any ideas what may cause this behavior and how to resolve it? (both examples don't use any custom CSS or such but they are accounts hosted at two different Universities) Thank you.

Comment: It is a difference in the themes being used. The example that works looks like the Blank Dynamic theme with Flat layout.

Comment: @T.Gibbons Hello. No that is not the case. I've tested all available layouts with no effect. To clarify, I have also updated the question to show this occurs irrespective of layout chosen (previous layout was simply there to save the space). So far I believe this is an issue with Qualtrics.

Comment: No, it is a CSS issue. If you don't have any Custom CSS, then it is a difference in the themes between the two accounts. Use the browser's inspect feature to figure out what is different.

Comment: The one which is working shows this CSS path: `html.JFEScope body#SurveyEngineBody ul#ui-id-5.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete.ui-front`
The which is not working shows this CSS path: `html.JFEScope body#SurveyEngineBody ul#ui-id-1.ui-autocomplete.ui-front.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content`
Only the order is different. Is it possible to somehow copy one theme to other? Unfortunately, I am not sure what to do on the CSS level...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment above, copy the CSS `html.JFEScope body#SurveyEngineBody ul#ui-id-5.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete.ui-front` rule from the working version to the Look&Feel>Custom CSS of the non-working version. The important part is the contents of the rule. Presumably they are different.

Although the classes are in a different order the only difference between the two selectors is the id of the ul element. Make sure you use the correct id (they may be different in the two surveys).

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but jquery autocomplete looks for `.ui-front` on a parent element; if it's not set you need to [explicitly add a selector](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo) with the appendTo option in your custom js code for that questions.

```
var yourSourceList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    $elem = jQuery('.QR-'+this.questionId),
    $elemParent = $elem.parent();
            
jQuery($elem).autocomplete({ 
    source: yourSourceList,
    minLength:3,
    appendTo: $elemParent
});
```